# SQL 2005 - Change compatibility level for current database without knowing name

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a challenge increasing the database compatibility level for the *current* database in SQL Server 2005. The `alter database ...` method doesn't work in SQL 2005, as it didn't have that syntax back then (it started in 2012). So I figured out I can do it like so:

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel [SomeDB], 80;
```

However, I need to do it for the *current* database, as the database name won't be known explicitly in this script. Joining another similar solution I found, I tried...

```
declare @dbname varchar(50)
set @dbname = DB_NAME()
declare @sql varchar(200)
set @sql = 'EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel '+@dbname+', 80'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

But it doesn't like this method - it spits out the following error:

> Stored procedure 'sys.sp_dbcmptlevel' can only be executed at the ad hoc level.

The reason this is in SQL 2005 is because this is a very large script (over 40,000 lines) which upgrades a database from SQL 7, and SQL 2005 was the last version which is able to restore a database from SQL 7.

How do I dynamically raise the database compatibility level from SQL 7 to SQL 2000 from SQL 2005 without explicitly knowing the database name?

Comment: Run the script from `sqlcmd`, passing the `-d` option to specify the database. This allows you to use the `SQLCMDDBNAME` built-in variable (e.g. `sqlcmd -d bar -Q "EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel [$(SQLCMDDBNAME)], 80"`). If you need to this for more than one database, using looping constructs in cmd/PowerShell is still more comfortable than T-SQL. If you absolutely, positively, *must* do this in pure T-SQL, I see no other option but to script creation of a job that runs this command in a T-SQL step, start it, then delete it. Incredibly clumsy and roundabout, but what can you do...

Comment: @JeroenMostert Indeed, I'm calling this SQL from Delphi anyway, where it's trivial to replace placeholders with dynamic SQL. I'm just looking to avoid all that jive. But if that's the only option, then I guess I'll have to make the code modify the script as necessary - or even better yet - have a function designated for the purpose of raising compatibility level on any given database.

Comment: Long story short, in SQL Server 2005, such a thing wasn't possible using direct TSQL. That ability came along (using tricks) in SQL Server 2012. So I'll need to do some dynamic script modifications.